# How to make a file converter for a Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, file, finder, file-conversion

I would like to create a file converter for a mac. Should I use xCode to do this, and where could I find code to make such an app. Are there tutorials for making file converters

Answer (score 0):

Xcode would probably be your best bet. For an idea on how to make one you can go to github and look and some public repos. Here is the link to the repo of the http://mirovideoconverter.com/

https://github.com/8planes/mirovideoconverter